# Flash Player slows down when I move mouse

Tags: mouse, flash

Whenever I move my mouse, my flash player slows down.
It happens only in flash games, not videos (from what I've seen so far); and it seems to only happens in Firefox, because whenever I use Chromium, I have no problem at all.
(It seems that it's not an add-on problem, because I've used FF with all add-ons disabled in safe mode, but there's no difference).

What it could be?

- Firefox 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
- Chromium-browser 28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1
- flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.297ubuntu0.13.04.1
- 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- about:support > http://paste.ubuntu.com/6019691/
- about:plugins > http://paste.ubuntu.com/6019692/
- about:support (no extensions but flash) > http://paste.ubuntu.com/6019695/
- about:plugins (no plugins but flash) > http://paste.ubuntu.com/6019694/

Question: If I wouldn't have hardware acceleration, wouldn't that mean that I should have the same problem with Chromium, or it's independent of each browser?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you also try a brand-new profile? See http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles for how to create a new profile.

Comment: @vasa1: I did it, but the problem persists.

Comment: As @Braiam suggested, please post the info from the "Graphics" section of `about:support` in your question.

Comment: @Braiam, I understand that the OP is automatically pinged so there's no need to mention the OP.

Comment: @Braiam: Answered in the EDIT part of my main question.

Comment: @Braiam Updated (thank you for the paste.ubuntu page). The problem persists.

Comment: Right click any flash content, then click "Settings...", you will get a small box, at the bottom left there is a kind of Monitor/Screen, click it, it should read "Enable Hardware Acceleration" if it's activated, disable it, if it's disabled, enable it. Restart Firefox between each change.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on the mouse/perfomance problem, [ask another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) for the last one.

In your case I would suggest forcing the activation of Hardware Acceleration. For some reason or other Mozilla decided to blacklist a bunch of cards because of some (very old) problems with the drivers that were solved in posterity, but they didn't bother to test again. That's for the reason, now to solve the problem:

1. Open a new tab and type `about:config`. We will be <strike>carefree</strike> carefull, I prommise
2. In the search box, write `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`, if no results come up, right click the empty area, point "New >" then select boolean.
3. Write `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`, hit ok.
4. Now the search came up with a result, make the value `true` by double clicking, or right click > Toggle. This is how it should looks like:

   [image]

   <sub>Please, ignore that it says Iceweasel, it's just Firefox rebranded.</sub>
5. Restart Firefox.

Comment: The problem persists. Only that this time this changed: "GPU Accelerated Windows 1/1 OpenGL"

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782107

try another browser, or Firefox 12 or lower